# unity ubuntu 20.04 no move option for files

Tags: unity

the move option has been removed in the file manager... is there a way to move file/folders without have to use the command line. I've tried various key cominations as in Mac OS while dragging and dropping, the files just get copied, not moved.

Comment: Are you using Unity or the default GNOME desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to cut and paste.
Select a file, press the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to cut, and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste it in the desired location.